# MySQL upsert (ON DUPLICATE KEY) using JDBC Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert, sql-update

I am trying to write a method to have an UPSERT functionality with a prepared statement in java. The code looks as follows;

```
public boolean addUserDeviceToken(String userid, String password, String deviceToken, Connection connection) {
    String addDeviceToken = "INSERT INTO swiped.Users (userid, password, deviceToken) VALUES( ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE devicetoken = ?";
    boolean result = false;

    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try {
        st = connection.prepareStatement(addDeviceToken);
        st.setString(1, userid);
        st.setString(2, password);
        st.setString(3, deviceToken);
        st.setString(4, deviceToken);
```

What I am unsure of is whether i use `st.executeQuery();` or `st.executeUpdate();` as surely it depends on the condition of the duplicate key?

What is the correct approach

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to get a resultSet, there's no result apart the number of insertions or updates, simply use [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()).

Extract from the javadoc :

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement