# Checking the data into database before insertion

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I need help in checking the data into the database before insertion.

**Issue:**

I have used the general method to insert the values into database.But I need to include this condition into my servlet code i.e if a data is already present in the database,then that data should not be inserted into the database and the remaining data should be inserted into the database.While doing this no alert should be raised to the user.

This is my code.

**products.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="web.Products"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <form method="post" action="Save_Products">   
<b>          
            Brand Name:<font color="green">
            <% String brand_name=(String)session.getAttribute("brand_name");
       out.print(brand_name);%> 
        <c:set var="brand_name" value="brand_name" scope="session"  />
       </font></b>         
            <table>            
                <tr>                
                    <th> Products</th> 
                    <th> Description </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
               <td> <b><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("list");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } %> </b></td>   

            <td><%for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\"/><br/>"); 
        } 

      }  
            %> </td>  

        </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr><td align="center">  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 
            </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Servlet code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Save_Products extends HttpServlet {
 static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdt";
     static final String dbUser = "root";
     static final String dbPass = "root";
    @Override
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection connection = null;  
            try{
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String brand_name =(String) session.getAttribute("brand_name");
String [] prod_list = request.getParameterValues("prod");
String [] desc_list = request.getParameterValues("desc");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection (dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);

String sql="insert into pdt_list(brand_name,product_name,desc)values(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
int num_values = Math.min(prod_list.size(), desc_list.size());

int count_updated = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
    prep.setString(1, brand_name);
    prep.setString(2, prod_list[i]);
    prep.setString(3,desc_list[i]);
    count_updated += prep.executeUpdate();
}
if(count_updated>0)
{    
   out.print("Products Saved Successfully...");
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Success.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);    
}
else{
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Failure.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);   
}

prep.close();
       }
     catch(Exception E){
//Any Exceptions will be caught here
System.out.println("The error is"+E.getMessage());

    }  

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("The error is"+ex.getMessage());
            }
                }

}

}
```

Comment: if you are looking of duplicates on table and your table has the same primary keys you are looking for duplicate you could use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL upsert (ON DUPLICATE KEY) using JDBC Prepared Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242002/mysql-upsert-on-duplicate-key-using-jdbc-prepared-statement)